# MySQL: Count and Group by hour for datetime ranges

Tags: mysql

given is this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `session_user` (
  `user_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `datetime_from` datetime NOT NULL,
  `datetime_end` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `mac` varchar(17) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`datetime_from`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `session_user` (user_id,datetime_from,datetime_end,mac) VALUES
     ('p0bjnvs','2020-09-06 00:26:43.000','2020-09-06 00:32:36.000','08:c5:e1:69:ea:ef'),
     ('xfehuwz','2020-09-06 00:31:50.000','2020-09-06 00:44:53.000','4c:66:41:13:fe:df'),
     ('ckltnqvk','2020-09-06 00:32:06.000','2020-09-06 01:34:57.000','a4:b8:05:ef:bf:c9'),
     ('spglpqk','2020-09-06 00:35:08.000','2020-09-06 00:45:27.000','ec:ce:d7:a5:5b:b3'),
     ('24um9x3','2020-09-06 00:35:17.000','2020-09-06 00:36:44.000','c0:1a:da:80:45:dd'),
     ('a9eqtb7','2020-09-06 00:35:45.000','2020-09-06 00:41:43.000','70:70:0d:04:4d:e9'),
     ('fd5q5cw','2020-09-06 00:36:23.000','2020-09-06 00:41:37.000','e6:23:16:7f:5b:6c'),
     ('bf04hz2','2020-09-06 00:36:40.000','2020-09-06 00:47:09.000','a4:4b:d5:ce:d4:4c'),
     ('8omlmvx','2020-09-06 00:37:00.000','2020-09-06 00:39:29.000','c6:dc:57:2e:13:bb'),
     ('3hscso6','2020-09-06 00:40:56.000','2020-09-06 00:53:09.000','dc:16:b2:e7:f2:9a');
INSERT INTO `session_user` (user_id,datetime_from,datetime_end,mac) VALUES
     ('oaj3cvb','2020-09-06 00:45:04.000','2020-09-06 01:17:40.000','a4:45:19:fa:51:80'),
     ('ch4371f','2020-09-06 00:45:34.000','2020-09-06 01:29:25.000','b8:7b:c5:58:d9:23'),
     ('91kqnu6','2020-09-06 00:51:18.000','2020-09-06 01:30:26.000','f0:18:98:e1:0b:fb'),
     ('ckzixwhx','2020-09-06 00:52:32.000','2020-09-06 00:59:11.000','b4:9c:df:5d:25:5c'),
     ('pnb2xfo','2020-09-06 00:58:53.000','2020-09-06 01:00:11.000','c0:d0:12:71:a8:ff'),
     ('ckkukkik','2020-09-06 01:04:12.000','2020-09-06 01:17:44.000','a4:08:ea:8b:d2:eb'),
     ('tobbzgv','2020-09-06 01:10:38.000','2020-09-06 01:24:49.000','dc:f7:56:6c:55:ec'),
     ('vja2dm7','2020-09-06 01:14:58.000','2020-09-06 01:36:34.000','4c:66:41:8b:9f:49'),
     ('rzq7pqp','2020-09-06 01:15:30.000','2020-09-06 01:37:13.000','3e:0f:b5:5d:cf:0c'),
     ('k48khjh','2020-09-06 01:15:31.000','2020-09-06 01:37:36.000','a8:db:03:65:73:21');
INSERT INTO `session_user` (user_id,datetime_from,datetime_end,mac) VALUES
     ('ow91esy','2020-09-06 01:15:36.000','2020-09-06 01:21:53.000','40:9c:28:24:33:f2'),
     ('77wtiq3','2020-09-06 01:16:58.000','2020-09-06 01:18:36.000','ce:81:26:16:32:46'),
     ('ne8fo03','2020-09-06 01:19:17.000','2020-09-06 01:21:56.000','bc:41:01:2b:19:92'),
     ('4ki8ss5','2020-09-06 01:21:15.000','2020-09-06 01:29:20.000','a2:c9:f0:72:17:69'),
     ('vksgbrik','2020-09-06 01:22:01.000','2020-09-06 01:35:13.000','cc:20:e8:b9:1c:b4'),
     ('ckkukkik','2020-09-06 01:23:23.000','2020-09-06 01:43:18.000','a4:08:ea:8b:d2:eb'),
     ('cfvtzfh','2020-09-06 01:23:59.000','2020-09-06 01:26:19.000','94:7b:e7:53:d4:19'),
     ('8ln88w2','2020-09-06 01:27:01.000','2020-09-06 01:28:07.000','78:67:d7:33:9d:17'),
     ('2gf35ay','2020-09-06 01:38:16.000','2020-09-06 02:04:00.000','ac:c1:ee:5e:17:ed'),
     ('tszpy8n','2020-09-06 01:38:18.000','2020-09-06 01:52:41.000','94:0c:98:31:c7:dd');
INSERT INTO `session_user` (user_id,datetime_from,datetime_end,mac) VALUES
     ('vw2elgw','2020-09-06 01:42:30.000','2020-09-06 01:47:33.000','bc:a5:8b:95:52:a5'),
     ('vksgbrik','2020-09-06 01:44:29.000','2020-09-06 02:46:10.000','cc:20:e8:b9:1c:b4'),
     ('ckltnqvk','2020-09-06 01:46:31.000','2020-09-06 02:12:29.000','a4:b8:05:ef:bf:c9'),
     ('ckkukkik','2020-09-06 01:48:33.000','2020-09-06 01:56:41.000','a4:08:ea:8b:d2:eb'),
     ('b93kanx','2020-09-06 01:55:34.000','2020-09-06 02:39:24.000','c4:06:83:8e:60:04'),
     ('tszpy8n','2020-09-06 01:59:00.000','2020-09-06 01:59:33.000','94:0c:98:31:c7:dd'),
     ('kgyflo8','2020-09-06 01:59:28.000','2020-09-06 02:04:42.000','38:47:bc:2d:02:d5'),
     ('kje5bkd','2020-09-06 02:00:34.000','2020-09-06 02:02:16.000','98:29:a6:ad:0d:76'),
     ('ckkukkik','2020-09-06 02:02:32.000','2020-09-06 02:03:17.000','a4:08:ea:8b:d2:eb'),
     ('ckkukkik','2020-09-06 02:09:27.000','2020-09-06 02:21:44.000','a4:08:ea:8b:d2:eb');
INSERT INTO `session_user` (user_id,datetime_from,datetime_end,mac) VALUES
     ('v5v6ex5','2020-09-06 02:15:14.000','2020-09-06 03:07:29.000','d0:d7:83:b5:17:b2'),
     ('jpaangj','2020-09-06 02:17:26.000','2020-09-06 03:04:23.000','6c:ab:31:36:10:87'),
     ('ot8fwnc','2020-09-06 02:18:51.000','2020-09-06 02:26:47.000','48:27:ea:cc:4d:70'),
     ('c18vv2q','2020-09-06 02:21:22.000','2020-09-06 02:38:33.000','68:e7:c2:df:40:f3'),
     ('zp19m4j','2020-09-06 02:23:00.000','2020-09-06 02:29:54.000','08:c5:e1:93:ce:de'),
     ('72oh0zp','2020-09-06 02:23:55.000','2020-09-06 02:31:42.000','78:67:d7:43:39:d5'),
     ('ckltnqvk','2020-09-06 02:24:30.000','2020-09-06 02:25:09.000','a4:b8:05:ef:bf:c9'),
     ('zjtxijf','2020-09-06 02:25:05.000','2020-09-06 02:39:21.000','8c:f5:a3:e6:66:b6'),
     ('ckkukkik','2020-09-06 02:30:45.000','2020-09-06 02:39:15.000','a4:08:ea:8b:d2:eb'),
     ('ckltnqvk','2020-09-06 02:32:40.000','2020-09-06 02:37:40.000','a4:b8:05:ef:bf:c9');
```

my challenge is to count users for every hour (0-23) they have an session in given datetime-range (from-end).
given are following sessions

```
from `2021-02-17 10:22:33` to end `2021-02-17 12:25:01`
from `2021-02-17 11:04:41` to end `2021-02-17 11:22:13`
from `2021-02-17 11:52:22` to end `2021-02-17 13:42:08`
```

so i want an result in this way:

```
hour|count|week_day|
----|-----|--------|
  10|    1|       x|
  11|    3|       x|
  12|    2|       x|
```

as you can see, there should always given the current `WEEKDAY()` so i get an result for the whole week.

my current start is this:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_from, '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00') BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_from, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') AND DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_end, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') THEN 0
        WHEN DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_from, '%Y-%m-%d 01:00:00') BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_from, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') AND DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_end, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') THEN 1
        WHEN DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_from, '%Y-%m-%d 02:00:00') BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_from, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') AND DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_end, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') THEN 2
        WHEN DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_from, '%Y-%m-%d 03:00:00') BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_from, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') AND DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_end, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') THEN 3
        WHEN DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_from, '%Y-%m-%d 04:00:00') BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_from, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') AND DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_end, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') THEN 4
        WHEN DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_from, '%Y-%m-%d 05:00:00') BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_from, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') AND DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_end, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') THEN 5
        WHEN DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_from, '%Y-%m-%d 06:00:00') BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_from, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') AND DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_end, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') THEN 6
        WHEN DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_from, '%Y-%m-%d 07:00:00') BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_from, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') AND DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_end, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') THEN 7
        WHEN DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_from, '%Y-%m-%d 08:00:00') BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_from, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') AND DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_end, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') THEN 8
        WHEN DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_from, '%Y-%m-%d 09:00:00') BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_from, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') AND DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_end, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') THEN 9
        WHEN DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_from, '%Y-%m-%d 10:00:00') BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_from, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') AND DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_end, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') THEN 10
        WHEN DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_from, '%Y-%m-%d 11:00:00') BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_from, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') AND DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_end, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') THEN 11
        WHEN DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_from, '%Y-%m-%d 12:00:00') BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_from, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') AND DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_end, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') THEN 12
        WHEN DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_from, '%Y-%m-%d 13:00:00') BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_from, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') AND DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_end, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') THEN 13
        WHEN DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_from, '%Y-%m-%d 14:00:00') BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_from, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') AND DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_end, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') THEN 14
        WHEN DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_from, '%Y-%m-%d 15:00:00') BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_from, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') AND DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_end, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') THEN 15
        WHEN DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_from, '%Y-%m-%d 16:00:00') BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_from, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') AND DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_end, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') THEN 16
        WHEN DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_from, '%Y-%m-%d 17:00:00') BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_from, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') AND DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_end, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') THEN 17
        WHEN DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_from, '%Y-%m-%d 18:00:00') BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_from, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') AND DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_end, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') THEN 18
        WHEN DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_from, '%Y-%m-%d 19:00:00') BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_from, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') AND DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_end, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') THEN 19
        WHEN DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_from, '%Y-%m-%d 20:00:00') BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_from, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') AND DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_end, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') THEN 20
        WHEN DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_from, '%Y-%m-%d 21:00:00') BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_from, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') AND DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_end, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') THEN 21
        WHEN DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_from, '%Y-%m-%d 22:00:00') BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_from, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') AND DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_end, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') THEN 22
        WHEN DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_from, '%Y-%m-%d 23:00:00') BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_from, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') AND DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_end, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') THEN 23
    END as `hour`,
    COUNT(1) as `count`,
    WEEKDAY(su.datetime_from) + 1 as `week_day`
FROM
    `session_user` su
WHERE
    YEARWEEK(su.datetime_from, 1) = 202103
GROUP BY
    `hour`,
    `week_day`
```

but i can not explain why this query brings also the same result:

```
SELECT
    extract(hour from su.datetime_from) as `hour`,
    COUNT(1) as `count`,
    WEEKDAY(su.datetime_from) + 1 as `week_day`
FROM
    `session_user` su
WHERE
    YEARWEEK(su.datetime_from, 1) = 202104
GROUP BY
    `hour`,
    `week_day`
```

in my oppion this should only count the hour from `datetime_from` and not all the hits between the `from` and `end` datetime... so why brings the first big query not the expected result?

EDIT:
the counting should happen by `mac`, so if an mac has two session in the same hour, it should counted by one!

EDIT2:
here is the missing fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3943e1/2

EDIT3:
okay, i see why both querys result in the same way. but how can i solve the problem?

EDIT4:

okay, this is my current result:

```
SELECT
    HOUR(h.dayhour) as `hour`,
    COUNT(DISTINCT su.mac) AS count,
    WEEKDAY(h.dayhour) + 1 as `week_day`
FROM
    ( with RECURSIVE week_hours(dayhour) as (
    select
        STR_TO_DATE("202105 Monday 0", "%X%V %W %H") as dayhour
union all
    select
        dayhour + INTERVAL 1 HOUR as dayhour
    from
        week_hours
    where
        dayhour < STR_TO_DATE("202105 Monday 23", "%X %V %W %H") + INTERVAL 6 DAY )
    SELECT
        dayhour
    from
        week_hours) AS h
LEFT JOIN `session_user` AS su ON
    h.dayhour BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(su.datetime_from, "%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00") AND su.datetime_end
WHERE
    YEARWEEK(su.datetime_from, 1) = 202105 
GROUP BY
    h.dayhour,
    week_day
```

maybe someone can optimize this query to earn an approved answer?

Comment: Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) - but that said, seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: that's not an question of displaying data, group and counting are core features of databases, or not?

Comment: There are no rows here within the specified ranges.

Comment: You want to count a session multiple times if it spans multiple hours? You need a join with a table that lists each hour, and the `ON` condition would be whether the hour is in the from-end range.

Comment: To generate the range of hours you could of course use `Recursive CTE` as also described here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/204513/187117. To eliminate duplicated `macs`, I suggest to also group by `mac`, maybe in another subquery / CTE

Answer (score 0):

One option is to join with a table that lists every hour in the day.

```
SELECT h.hour, COUNT(*) AS count, WEEKDAY(su.datetime_from) + 1 as `week_day`
FROM (SELECT 0 AS hour UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 ... UNION SELECT 23) AS h
LEFT JOIN session_USER AS su ON h.hour BETWEEN HOUR(su.datetime_from) AND HOUR(su.datetime_end)
WHERE YEARWEEK(su.datetime_from, 1) = 202104
GROUP BY h.hour, week_day
```

However, this won't work correctly for sessions that cross over midnight. For that, you need a more complicated condition that checks the order of `datetime_from` and `datetime_end`.

```
LEFT JOIN session_USER AS su 
    ON IF(HOUR(su.datetime_from) < HOUR(su.datetime_end),
          h.hour BETWEEN HOUR(su.datetime_from) AND HOUR(su.datetime_end),
          h.hour >= HOUR(su.datetime_end) OR h.hour <= HOUR(su.datetime_from))
```

This still assumes that sessions are less than 1 day long.

Comment: okay, that's realy cool! but it is true, i have sessions they are running some days. so we have to think about it ... maybe we select first all hours/datetimes from the entry week?

Comment: so this is an mariaDB server, i'm trying to use "recursive CTE" https://mariadb.com/kb/en/recursive-common-table-expressions-overview/, maybe you can help again?

Comment: You could use `CASE` with more conditions, so if from and end are multiple days apart they match all hours.